# How to deploy an already built react app with express.js backend to heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I have been working on a project for a while now and want to know if anyone has some resources for how to deploy a site that is already built with react and uses an express.js backend to heroku. Every tutorial I have found online is for setting one up for deployment on creating, but since this site has already been created I cant find a way to deploy it now.

Comment: When you say "already built" do you mean the webpack artifacts are committed to git? They will usually be in a folder like /build/
Hosting in Heroku should be the same as for any other ExpressJS application which includes static content.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check your package.json to see if it defines the scripts to launch the application. Typically you would need to create a Procfile that looks like this...

```
web: npm run start
```

If the package.json defines a script for "start". Otherwise it might look like...

```
web: node index.js
```

or

```
web: node server
```

Depending how your application starts.

The fact that it's hosting React shouldn't make a difference if the bundle is already built. It's the same process as hosting any other static content.